# How to calculate distance matrix from fasta?

Tags: r, fasta, statistics

I’d like to perform the following, but I am having difficulty.

I want to convert amino acid sequences in multifasta files into matrices (or vectors) with Euclidean distance and Pearson correlation coefficient.

If you know a solution, please let me know. Thanking you in advance.

#### File1

```
>BDP27474.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFLVLLPL
>BDP27485.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFLVLLPL
```

#### File2

```
>BDD77411.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFLVLLPL
>BDD77515.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFFVLLPL
```

#### Code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ape)
library(Biostrings)

naseq1 <- readAAStringSet("File1.fasta")
naseq2 <- readAAStringSet("File2.fasta")

dist.aa(naseq1)
dist.aa(naseq2)

##Error in numeric(n * (n - 1)/2) : invalid 'length' argument
```

#### Add info.

iOS 10.15, Rstudio cloud

Comment: There's no matrix for file1 because MFVFLVLLPL and MFVFLVLLPL are identical

Comment: You are probably looking for Biostrings::stringDist to compare both strings